# NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData causing app to crash after alamofire migration

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm new to iOS and swift development. I recently migrated alamofire lib to V3.0 which generated code errors. I managed to solve them all. However there is a last problem. I have a class named Webservices used to invoke web services. It has a method called postCustomLogin. In one of my viewcontrollers I'm calling it, when I run the app it crashes at this line :

```
errorCode = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(result.value as! NSData , options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments ) as! NSString
```

Here is the definition of the function :

```
class func postCustomLogin(email: String, password: String, completionHandler: ( Result<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void) {
 Alamofire.request(.POST, baseURL + "CustomLogin", parameters: ["email": email, "password": password])
        .validate()
        .responseJSON {(response) in
            if (response.result.isSuccess) {
                if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
                   User.createEntityWithDictionnary(jsonDict)
                    //Save                    NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext().MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
                }
            }
            completionHandler(response.result)
    }
}
```

and here is where I'm calling the function :

```
Webservices.postCustomLogin(user!, password: password!, completionHandler: { (result) in
            do {
                if (result.value != nil)
                {
                     errorCode = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(result.value as! NSData , options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments ) as! NSString//crash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forcing the unwrap of your optionals. If your `result.value` isn't a `NSData` or `try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(result.value as! NSData , options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments ) as! NSString//crash` isn't a `NSString` your app crash. Try with this code for safely unwrap:

```
if let resultData = result.value as? NSData{
    if let anErrorCode = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(resultData , options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments ) as? NSString
    error = anErrorCode
    ....
    ....
}
```